# tex4ht: indexentries/structure of the .ind-file

Tags: indexing, tex4ht

Running htlatex 2 times with a makeindex command in-between delivers a working .ind file but with page numbers as linktags in the corresponding .html output which make no sense for users visting the web page.

How can I exchange/addto the info in the LNK-section of the corresponding .ind for a self-chosen text ?

Or where can I find infos about the structure of the .ind or/and the corresponding .4dx-file ?

P.S. My goal is exchanging the page numbers(s) for a (sub)section entry of the LaTeX source to imitate the index structure O'Reilly is using in its E-Books.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

I've created new project, [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht), which will be collection of various packages for simplification of `tex4ht` usage. These packages are possible to include in the `.cfg` file. First package is `indexing4ht`, for working with indexes.

Place files `indexing4ht.4ht` and `indexing4ht.sty` in your working directory and add `\RequirePackage{indexing4ht}` to the `.cfg` file, before `\Preamble` command. For example:

```
\usepackage{indexing4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml,3}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

in this example, `3` option is used to break sections into standalone html files

Now some sample document, `sample.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\makeindex[name=names]
\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}
\index{section}
\subsection{first}

\index[names]{Einstein, Albert}
\index{hello}\index{world}

\subsection{second}
\index[names]{Knuth, Donald}
\index{hello}
\index{not world}
\subsubsection{sub sub section}
\index{hello|definition}
\index{Latex@\LaTeX}
\index{uff|see{hello}}
\index{off|seealso{hello}}
\index{Some bold@\textbf{Some bold}}
\printindex
\printindex[names]
\end{document}
```

only `imakeidx` package is supported at the moment, because it provides easy method for index writing customization. Note that two different indices are used, default for keywords, and names. Also `see` and `seealso` attributes are used.

Now we can compile the document with

```
htlatex sample cfgfilename
```

three important files will be created, `sample.idx`, `names.idx` and `sample.xdy`. `sample.xdy` is configuration file for `xindy` index processor. `makeindex` isn't supported.

When you look at `names.idx`:

```
\indexentry{Einstein, Albert}{1.1}
\indexentry{Knuth, Donald}{1.2}
```

you can see that `section` numbers are used instead of page numbers. This is default configuration, but it can be configured to use different locations than section numbers, for example paragraphs or link back to `\index` commands.

Now we need to process `.idx` files with `xindy`:

```
xindy -L english -C utf8 -M sample sample.idx
xindy -L english -C utf8 -M sample names.idx
```

resulting `names.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{E}
  \item \idxkeyword{Einstein, Albert}, \idxlocator{1.1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{K}
  \item \idxkeyword{Knuth, Donald}, \idxlocator{1.2}

\end{theindex}
```

you can see that `\idxkeyword` and `\idxlocator` commands are used, these are used for cross-referencing.

Because commands in index entries were used in our samples, we need to take care of them, because they would cause problems in cross-reference handling. The problematic ones are these:

```
\index{Latex@\LaTeX}
\index{Some bold@\textbf{Some bold}}
```

Package `gettitlestring` is used for cleaning of index entries, we need to provide configuration for used commands in the `.cfg` file:

```
\usepackage{indexing4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml,3}
\GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
\renewcommand\textbf[1]{#1}%
\renewcommand\LaTeX{LaTeX}
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

see contents of `\GetTitleStringDisableCommands`. Definition for each command used in index entry names should be placed here.

Now compile with

```
htlatex sample cfgfilename
```

resulting main index:

[image]

links on section numbers point back to sections where index entry was saved. note that `see` and `seealso` attributes produce links to referenced index entries.

[image]