# htlatex, imakeidx, and textit in an index entry

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, imakeidx

I'm using htlatex to create an ebook.

For some customization reasons, I need to use imakeidx instead of makeidx. Additionally, some of my index entries are using \textit{}, e.g. \index{\textit{example}}.

This works fine with standard latex. But with htlatex, it's a problem. Specifically, for the index I need to run:

```
tex '\def\filename{{doc}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'
```

and it's getting tripped up by the \textit{} in the index entry. The error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \indexentry{\textit
                   {example}}{1}
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document} 

An \textit{example}\index{\textit{example}}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The commands I'm using to process this are:

```
htlatex doc "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
tex '\def\filename{{doc}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'
makeindex -o doc.ind doc.4dx
htlatex doc "xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

If I change imakeidx to makeidx, it works. But, I need to use imakeidx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that the `\textit` command is executed somewhere in the index processing. Because the indexing is done by plain TeX, it doesn't know LaTeX commands, as `\textit` is. The easiest solution is to define dummy `\textit` macro:

```
tex '\def\textit#1{#1}\def\filename{{sample}{idx}{4dx}{ind}} \input idxmake.4ht'
```

This version compiles without issues and the output seems correct:

[image]

Note that there is also another solution for indexing, using Xindy ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210849/2891), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348149/2891)), which uses section numbers instead of page numbers for locators. This may be more useful than page numbers which are used by default.

Comment: This does solve my problem with \textit{} not being defined. But, there appear to be larger issues with idxmake.4ht not being compatible with imakeidx; in the above solution doc.ind is coming from htlatex itself. I ended up using the Xindy approach you @michal.h21 mentioned, via your [helpers4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht) package.